# Connect iPhone with Windows computer Wirelessly without a network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iphone, ad-hoc-network, resilio-sync

I would like to connect an iPhone and a Windows computer without access to wifi or any other network. The iPhone will be getting data on it (pictures and times) for a track meet and I need to pass this data to the laptop and then have it delete on the phone so the phone doesn't fill up and so the laptop can start tallying the results.

I was thinking a mesh network with [Resilio sync](https://www.resilio.com/) might be able to do it but I'm not really sure. [Open Garden](https://www.opengarden.com/) seems to have the capability between phones but it is also for developers. But I would think there is some solution out there that works already.

I'm not the one that will actually be implementing this. I am asking on behalf of someone else. I should be able to field any questions though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have full access to the computer. You can use iTunes to sync the devices even without wifi? I'm not an Apple user otherwise I might have known that.

Comment: Sounds like that's your answer then. Use iTunes, installed on the Windows computer, and sync the iPhone. Then you can process the pictures and data on the computer while the iPhone is gathering more data. Though I have no idea how you plan to save the "times" let alone transfer them, unless you're using screen captures of the timer. I personally haven't used iTunes in years, so I can't say what is the best workflow for getting the data and then deleting it on the iPhone. I'm sure you'll have to copy the sync'd data to another folder on the computer before deleting them in the sync, though.

Comment: Wait. So are you saying to connect the phone to the computer with a wire? Because it needs to be wireless, ideally is what I was hoping for.

Comment: If the computer has wireless capability, then you don't need to use the USB cord, though it would probably be better anyway. You can sync the iPhone over USB or wifi, as long as the phone is new enough. I'm not 100%, but I think wifi sync was introduced in iOS 6.1, which will run on iPhones as old as version 4. The iPhone does have to be "plugged in to power and connected to Wi-Fi". That's easy enough to do by using one of those recharging battery packs. You'll probably need to do that anyway to keep the iPhone running while taking all those photos.